# Bootstrap CSS - Media-right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement some bootrap css - I don't want the entire css so i've just copied some css for certain components such as alerts and the media component.

However the media-right css doesn't seem to work. I have the following:

```
<style> 
  .media,
  .media-body {
   overflow: hidden;
   zoom: 1;
  }
 .media, .media .media {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
.media-body,
.media-left,
.media-right {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
}
.media-middle {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.media-left,
.media > .pull-left {
   padding-right: 25px;
}            
.media-right, 
.media > .pull-right {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.media-object {
    display: block;
}
.media-heading {
   margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.media-body p {
     margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

```
<div class="media">
     <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
            <a href="#">Football</a> 
        </h4>
        <p>xyz</p>
     </div>                                                                                                                     
     <div class="media-right" style="width:200px">
        <img class="media-object" src="xyx" alt="">
     </div>                                                         
</div>
```

The image is to the right of the media-body but when there isn't enough content the image looks like it's in the middle.

Is there some css I'm missing or how do i ensure the image is to the right even when there is no content?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the CSS from the `@media` too, there are some `pull-right` and `pull-left` classes there. It should fix your problem for different size of screens.